# Considerations for spray booth filtration

Tags: post-processing, safety

I am getting to the point where I want to start post-processing my 3D prints more heavily, i.e. sanding, polishing, painting. I am currently using PLA but will be working with resin and possibly other FDM materials like ABS or PETG. I looking at making a spray booth that can handle both the sanding and airbrushing of models.

What considerations do I need to take into account? What type of filtration will I need? Is a HEPA filter needed or recommended? What other hazards or concerns?

Comment: There is nothing about it that would be special to 3D printing - it would be a simple spray booth - for which by the way there are industrial requirements to be inside and wear respirators.

Comment: @Trish My question is dealing with the particulate matter from sanding PLA, ABS, PETG, or resin-based models. I added the note about airbrushing because I thought it would be another consideration in the selection of the filter. I am open to suggestions to improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are many factors that play in this.

For example if your room has proper air flow. Next to window. What is the season because having the window open during winter can cause your 3d printer to malfunction. You should look at this chart to get a overall view of what to get.

I recommend HEPA that blocks up to 99.97 because it can block a lot more and because it can be easily bought. Also I recommend MERV 11 filters because they are widely available and can block many 3d printing debris which you don't want to inhale.

[image: Particle size chart]

https://www.sentryair.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/filter-comparisonchart.jpg